# How to conduct a non-parametric shape test?

Tags: r

I think the code below is the parametric way of the shape test, although there may be some errors:

```
# Shape test
glu <- diabetes$Glucose
BPre <- diabetes$BloodPressure
plot(density(glu))
plot(density(BPre))
# To compare the shape, first to standardize them
glu1<- (glu - mean(glu)) / sd(glu)
BPre1 <- (BPre - mean(BPre)) / sd(BPre)


plot(density(glu1))
lines(density(BPre1), col = "red")


# Compute test statistic 
q <- c(0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9)
x1 <- quantile(glu1, probs = q)
x2 <- quantile(BPre1, probs = q)        
tstat <- sum(abs(x1 - x2))        
tstat        
s1 <- rnorm(length(glu1))
s2 <- rnorm(length(BPre1))

# Describe the population and generate one synthetic sample
f1 <- function()
{
    s1 <- rnorm(length(glu1))
    s2 <- rnorm(length(BPre1))
    q <- c(0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9)
    x1 <- quantile(s1, probs = q)
    x2 <- quantile(s2, probs = q)        
    return(sum(abs(x1 - x2)))

}

# Create sampling distribution
sdist <- replicate(10000, f1())
# Plot sampling distribution & create p-value
plot(density(sdist))
abline(v = tstat, col = "dark red" )
# Gap
gap <- abs(mean(sdist) - tstat)
abline(v = mean(sdist) + c(-1,1) * gap, col = "dark orange")
s1 <- sdist[sdist <(mean(sdist - gap)) | sdist >(mean(sdist + gap))]
pvalue <- length(s1) / length(sdist)
pvalue
```

I was wondering if I can do the non-parametric shape test with the same data. My intuition told me is possible. I just need a little inspiration on how to transform glu1 and BPres to a non-parametric way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bootstrapping, by using the Sample function and draw from the same sample.

Only these below 2 commands will change to a sample() function. Replace will be True.You will draw from glu1 and Bpre1.With the same length.

s1 <- rnorm(length(glu1))
s2 <- rnorm(length(BPre1))

-- Go Huskies